# Gaussian process regression on a graph

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, uncertainty, graph-theory

I am looking for a way to do Gaussian process regression on a weighted graph. Analogously to the prototypical GPR plot, I made a drawing to make it more clear:

[image: graph with uncertainty intervals]

The filled nodes have a training point and the hollow nodes/edges don't. The blob around the graph is the variance. Blowing up one of the forks, it might look like this:

[image: blow up of a fork]

where the vertical axis is the target variable and the horizontal axes correspond to the edges.

I hope the explanation makes sense. I also appreciate pointers to similar ideas of propagating uncertainty in noneuclidean space.

Comment: Look at this [arXiv: Gaussian processes on graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05776.pdf)

Comment: Ah yes, I found that one as well, but it's so dense that I wasn't able to really evaluate whether it really is what I'm looking for, much less apply it.